# How do I achieve the following pivot in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data of the following form:

| Date | User_ID | Data_Desc | Data_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | Submission Time | 124600 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | E-mail Address | john@doe |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | Submission Time | 142200 |
| 2022-01-02 | 3 | Phone Number | 000-000-0000 |

I would like to pivot the data in such a way that the 'Data_Desc' fields become columns and the corresponding 'Data_Value' as the column value. I'm not an expert in pivots and only have used them in textbook cases with aggregate values so having some trouble figuring out how to do this.

Key point to note is that if a particular 'Date' and 'User ID' combination doesn't have a row for a particular field, I'd just want the value to be null. So the above example would look like:

| Date | User_ID | Submission Time | E-mail Address | Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 124600 | john@doe | (null) |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 142200 | (null) | (null) |
| 2022-01-02 | 3 | (null) | (null) | 000-000-0000 |

How can this be achieved using a Spark SQL expression?

Comment: Conditional aggregation - `max(case when data_desc = 'Submission Time' then data_value end), ...`